# New Post-type or added Custom-fields?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I want to customize my WP theme and add to each post that I publish in my website a few more fields.
The fields are:

- **Importance** (rank 1-5)
- **Date** - the Month that the data in the post cover
- **Type** - the type of the information covered in the post (one of 3-4 type options)

Then, I want that my website to include search page that will be able to search posts based on these fields (and also on fields in the regular post like tags)

**My question** - Should I create new post type for this matter or adding to custom fields to WP post would be good enough solution?

Comment: If you want to maintain this post as separately create new post type or else use WP post. Adding custom field is same for both. I think your solution will work. You can try

Comment: you mean that both solutions will work? why did you answer in comment and not as an answer below?

Comment: Yup. I think comment is enough for this

Comment: Custom fields is the way to go (toolset types plugin is an easy solution) but notice the WP  search wont target these fields you may need to modify the search function or use relevanssi plugin